# Java 7: get Path of resource (as object of type Path)

Tags: nio, java-7

I'm using the features of Java 7 to read in a file. For that purpose I need an object of type `Path`. In my code, I use the `getResource()` function to get the relative path (of type `URL`) to a file.

However, now I have the problem that I don't really now how to get from an object of type `URL` to an object of type `Path` easily (**without** having to go through castings to e.g. to `URI` then to `File` and from that to `Path`)?

Here an example to show you what I would like to do:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("file.txt");
Path path = (new File(url.toURI())).toPath(); //is there an easier way?
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

So is there an easier way to achieve that and not having to do that code mess on line 2?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about

```
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

It is not proper to create a File from your URL, since it's gotten from the classpath and the file may actually be within a jar.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of path do you get back if the resource actually was in a jar?

Answer (score 0):

In Scala would be

```scala
import java.nio.file.Paths

val resource = getClass.getResource("myfile.txt")
val path = Paths.get(resource.toURI)
```

In Java should be the same (with slightly different syntax)

Comment: Although true, I don't see how this answer really provides anything that the other answer hasn't provided already.

Comment: It does show how to get the uri of the resource.